# How do I dynamically invoke non-class methods in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

```
def greet() {
    println "Hello, Groovy!"
}

greet() // How to call this function dynamically?
```

Comment: what do you  mean by "dynamically"?

Comment: For example: def m = "greet", calling this method like "$m"().
This works if the method greet() belongs to a class.

Comment: @AndyXiao In Groovy every method belongs to some class. A Groovy script for instance compiles to a class that extends `groovy.lang.Script` and the name of this class is taken from script file name (e.g. if your script is named `test.groovy` then a class like `public class test extends groovy.lang.Script {}` gets generated). All methods defined in Groovy script belong automatically to this class. So there is no such thing like non-class method in Groovy.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean you want to call it by name:

```
def greet() {
    println "Hello Groovy!"
}

def name = "greet"

"$name"()
```

Should work